# Does a brown Pieris brassicae chrysalis indicate it is dead?

Tags: zoology, entomology, development

I have been breeding *Pieris brassicae* larvae in a glass tank indoors for my own personal observation. One of them, after the fifth instar, has moulted into a chrysalis. After 5 days of development in which the pupa changed colour accordingly to the information I had researched, going from a vibrant green to a paler green with black, white and yellow dots, the chrysalis has turned light brown on the sixth day.
I have found no correspondence of this in any of the sources, articles and videos I have studied. Does it indicate that the pupa is dead / stressed? (I am keeping the larvae at room temperature, i.e. 22°C and under a bright led light that is used to light up the whole room)
[image][image][image]

Comment: Did you do a google image search? I found [this](https://bugguide.net/node/view/621745) and others like it.  But time will tell. When my chrysalises die (different butterflies), they do turn brown, but they also appear dehydrated. IOW, they *look* dead.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think I should move them to a cooler space, (e.g. outside)? Or perhaps the bright led lighting I am using has a role in all of this?

Comment: I can't help you with that. I can tell you that most of the chrysalises that die for me were unrelated to the conditions in which metamorphosis was occurring. The caterpillar could have been stressed into pupating early or infected/parasitized (it's pretty awful to see a wasp come out of a Monarch chrysalis.) As I said, time will tell, and it's more likely than not that it would have died anyway.